# Jackson format LocalDate on whole class as strings

Tags: java, jackson

I noticed jackson turns `LocalDate`s to `[2018,06,01]` which sucks

I can annotate a specific variable/method for it to be properly formatted like so:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
LocalDate date;
```

Which is fine but I have several `LocalDate`s in my class, I'd rather have a single class level annotation, so: Is there an annotation I can use on my class to format them automatically? (I already tried googled but found nothing)

Ideally I want something like:

```
@JacksonPlsFormatLocalDatesCorrectly
class FullOfLocalDatesDTO { /* Dang thing be full o local dates yo */}
```

Comment: If this format is a standard of yours, you're supposed to set it on the general ObjectMapper, with setDateFormat(). If you have varying standards around your application and no knowledge of a way to have different ObjectMappers for different cases, well that's binding for you. Isn't it so helpful? Just put the annotation everywhere.